# How to identify if an executable was installed by MS Click-to-Run installer?

Tags: installer

How to identify, if an executable was installed by MS Click-to-Run installer?

For a classic MSI installer I can just open the MSI file with tools like Orca and then I can easily see if a given file was part of this installation. But how can I check the same for any Click-to-Run installation?

E.g. I want to check, if outlook.exe is still the original one being installed or if it may be tampered. Any ideas?

Comment: [If you are asking about Office, only volume license editions of Office, can be installed with an MSI. Every other version is Click2Run. Are you asking about Office?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-installed-with-click-to-run-and-windows-installer-on-same-computer-isn-t-supported-30775ef4-fa77-4f47-98fb-c5826a6926cd#:~:text=Click-to-Run%20is%20the%20technology%20used%20to%20install%20Microsoft,Microsoft%20Office%20Professional%20Plus%20and%20Microsoft%20Office%20Standard.).

Comment: If you are not using an unsupported version Office with a volume license, then it was installed with a Click2Run installer.

Comment: See [Use the Office offline installer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-office-offline-installer-f0a85fe7-118f-41cb-a791-d59cef96ad1c) how to download the offline installer which is just an `.exe`. This requires a valid subscription. Then use 7Zip to peek inside.

Comment: @harrymc - The offline installer with still be a Click2Run installer not a MSI installer.

Comment: @Ramhound: Are you sure? This would not be defined as Offline.

Comment: You can have a offline Click2Run installer. I can only tell you that only VLK installs of older unsupported versions of Office are MSI.

Comment: Can someone please focus on my question? I dont see, how C2R check the consistency of a streamed executable internally. I need this info for a SAM project to identify, if a given C2R package is actually "used" (running EXE from that installer).

Comment: I installled the deployment toolkit to download the offline-package, but still cannot see any hashes for the files in that package.

Comment: Update: I could drill down the issue to the initial CAB-file http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60/office/data/16.0.15128.20224/s320.cab . It includes a file "stream.....db" which looks promising. It has a content-header of C2RxUnityDB. But I dont know how to open it.